# Why Python loop slowingdown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, while-loop

I create a `while` loop and `print` the timestamp on every loop. At the beginning I got a performance of about 33 loops by second. However, longer it takes, slower it gets. At 3 minutes, I have a performance of 2 loops by second. I tried to use `threading.Timer` instead, but it does the same thing. I am aware that Memory and Complexity of calculations can be an issue, but it doesn't seem to be the case in that scenario.

How can I avoid that lack of performance as I want to run the code for hours?  Your help would be really appreciated.

```
import time

while(True):
    print(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
```

Output

```
1556756682157
1556756682216
1556756682240
1556756682269
1556756682296
1556756682324
1556756682358
1556756682387
1556756682415
1556756682441
1556756682470
1556756682501
1556756682556
... // After 3 minutes
1556756860002
1556756860884
1556756861240
1556756861669
1556756862596
1556756863324
1556756863858
1556756864387
```

Comment: What are you doing in the loop?

Comment: It is most probably printing to the console that slows it down.

Comment: How many lines in the console are there at the time of slowing down? Selcuk may be right. I know my Clojure REPL slows to a crawl as soon as I have a few hundred thousand entries.

Comment: It is literally the whole code, there is no more process than it. @Selcuk this is what I am thinking too, the queue list of the console print can slow it down I guess. Carcigenicate, one line at the time

Comment: On that [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7lzbpu/how_much_does_printing_out_words_slow_down_my/) they are saying `print` can considerably slow down too. So I will try to get rid of it and test it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried to log it in the file but it doesn't change this lags. It is still getting slower with time.

Comment: @G33kMan It may be one line at a time, but lines accumulate and eat memory, and memory shortages can cause lag. Again, how many lines are printed at the time that the lag starts? And printing to find can have similar problems depending on how you're feeling with the file.

Comment: @Carcigenicate 3600 timestamps later the lags pass the 20 millisecs to 200. The lags raise gradually, and can be felt after few seconds. For the print lines accumulate and eat memory, I think you are right on. However, when I used `logging.info(timestamp)` inside the loop and `logging.basicConfig(filename='info.log',level=logging.DEBUG)` before, the same lag is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on test done [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7lzbpu/how_much_does_printing_out_words_slow_down_my/), the print can considerably slow down your loop. Remiove the print and your speed shouldn't decrease that fast anymore. See below the example:

```
from time import time

start = time()
for i in range(1_000_000):
    print(i)
print(f'run time for printing: {time() - start}')

start = time()
for _ in range(1_000_000):
    pass
print(f'run time for no printing: {time() - start}')

this is what it printed:

# a ton of numbers above this line from printing

run time for printing: 7.047402858734131
run time for no printing: 0.0870048999786377
```